# Change texture colors using shaders

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

I'm trying to change texture colors inside the GLSL context - **doing so before the beginning of the OpenGL pipeline is not an option**.

I have tried the following approach:

**Vertex Shader**

```
attribute highp vec2 a_TexCoord;
uniform highp mat3 u_TextureMatrix;
varying highp vec2 v_TexCoord;
highp vec4 calculatePosition();
void main()
{
    gl_Position = calculatePosition();
    v_TexCoord = (u_TextureMatrix * vec3(a_TexCoord,1.0)).xy;
}
attribute highp vec2 a_Vertex;
uniform highp mat3 u_TransformMatrix;
uniform highp mat3 u_ProjectionMatrix;
highp vec4 calculatePosition() {
    return vec4(u_ProjectionMatrix * u_TransformMatrix * vec3(a_Vertex.xy, 1.0), 1.0);
}
```

**Fragment Shader**

```
uniform lowp float u_Opacity;
lowp vec4 calculatePixel();
void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = calculatePixel();
    gl_FragColor.a *= u_Opacity;
}
varying mediump vec2 v_TexCoord;
uniform lowp vec4 u_Color;
uniform sampler2D u_Tex0;
lowp vec4 calculatePixel() {
    vec4 tex = texture2D(u_Tex0, v_TexCoord);
    tex.xyz -= (100.0 / 255.0);
    if (tex.x < 0.0) { tex.x += 1.0; }
    if (tex.y < 0.0) { tex.y += 1.0; }
    if (tex.z < 0.0) { tex.z += 1.0; }
    return tex * u_Color;
}
```

This code works **EXCEPT** for the cases when **Interpolation** is applied (`GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR`), when things start to look really bad because the filtering happens before the Fragment Shader so I don't get to change the colors **PRIOR** when it's reliable to do so.

I'm developing a game that has as requirement supporting really old hardware (from as early as 2008) and that's why I'm using really obsolete GLSL code (version 120 compatible).

Is there a way to change Texture colors anywhere in the pipeline **BEFORE** the **rasterization** kicks in?

Comment: What you ask for requires either modifying the texture or interpolating manually in the shader. You may get better help here if you elaborate WHY  "doing so before the beginning of the OpenGL pipeline is not an option." WHY can't you maintain the correct values in your texture, potentially updating it with `glTexSubImage` if it changes after the first initialization?

Comment: I'm trying to protect the textures from one specific application that rips content from the GPU ram. So when they dump the memory they'll get the wrong colors in their resulting files. I know it's a very very flimsy security measure, but it works pretty good in my case.

Comment: Do you really think they can't undo your color transformation? If so your only option is to sample with `GL_NEAREST` and do all the filtering in the shader. That's going to be a lot slower than using the hardware texture filtering unit. That being said, such "security by obscurity" measures aren't worth the trouble, and you're better to invest your time in something else.

Comment: @AlexandreSeverino reverse engineers will simply run your program in renderdoc, look the draw call where the texture is being used and read the shader code that fetches the textures. renderdoc can decompile shaders. – Your approach will slow down reverse engineers by maybe half a minute.